# Wordpress paginate_links without showing total posts?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I've got two loops on my front page that are both using pagination - I've managed to find code to get this to work, pasted below.  Is it possible to have paginate_links not show my total number of posts? Currently it looks like: **1, 2, 3...526. Next**.  I'd prefer: **1, 2, 3... Next**.

Current code:

```
            // Courtesy of Boone Gorges

            $paged1 = isset( $_GET['paged1'] ) ? (int) $_GET['paged1'] : 1;
            $paged2 = isset( $_GET['paged2'] ) ? (int) $_GET['paged2'] : 1;

            // Custom Loop with Pagination 1
            // http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Usage
            $args1 = array(
                'paged'          => $paged1, // http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'category_name'  => 'wod'
            );
            $query1 = new WP_Query( $args1 );

            while ( $query1->have_posts() ) : $query1->the_post();
                echo '<h4>';
                the_date();
                echo '</h4>';
                the_content();
                echo '<hr>';
            endwhile;

            // http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links
            $pag_args1 = array(
                'format'   => '?paged1=%#%',
                'current'  => $paged1,
                'total'    => $query1->max_num_pages,
        'show_all' => False,
                'add_args' => array( 'paged2' => $paged2 ),
        'prev_text' => 'Next',  
            'next_text' => 'Prev'
            );
            echo paginate_links( $pag_args1 );
        ?>
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links have you tried setting `end_size` to 0?

Comment: Tried setting end_size => 0, with no effect.

Comment: You are right, the 0 is reset to 1 in the code. You can try setting the `type` to `array` and format it to your needs

Comment: I'm pretty helpless when it comes to creating PHP coding.  This is mostly a copy/paste/edit job.  Can you send me in the right direction to go about your suggestion?  Thanks, Mark!

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed the same problem. Here is how:

1) get the pagination with type array

```
$pagination = paginate_links(array(
    ....
    'type' => 'array',
));
```

2) remove the second last item from the array

```
unset($pagination[sizeof($pagination)-2]);
```

3) build the list from the array

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($pagination as $pag)
{
  echo '<li>';
  echo $pag;
  echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: remove just the element on index last-2 could remove a wanted link if the current page is one before the last one